# Dropbox Enterprise in conjunction with Dropbox App Functionality

Tags: integration, dropbox, dropbox-api

We currently have Dropbox App integration. We have a user authenticate and Dropbox creates a folder on the user's system, so they can place files there that we can read.

For Dropbox Enterprise support (http://www.dropbox.com/enterprise), is there a way for both app and multiple users to work together?

If the admin put two files in the app/folder, named A & B, then gave access to A to some users, and access to B to other users, how do we determine who sees what in our system?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. Can you edit your question with some more specific information? By "Dropbox Enterprise support" are you referring to using the [Dropbox Business API](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/teams)?

Comment: thanks for comment, added link to Dropbox enterprise. I don't believe the specific Dropbox Business API would be useful for our integration. The customer just wants to control who sees what on the Dropbox side, and have our integration honor that.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. When using the Dropbox API, any kind of account can link to it, e.g., Basic, Pro, Business, or Enterprise. The functionality is the same for each, e.g, file uploading/downloading, etc. (The Dropbox Business API offers access to functionality that is specific to Business/Enterprise accounts.) I'm still not sure I understand the rest of your question though. If you already have a Dropbox API integration, is it not behaving the way you want for these accounts?

Comment: I modified the question. Trying to understand how to set it up for one app shared by many users.

Comment: I'm still not sure I follow. Can you perhaps add the code you have so far and add some detail around what is and isn't working?